# WPF UI Related question

Tags: wpf

realy i don't know what i should title this problem, i hope to "WPF UI Related question" is accept able.
consider something like that form who you explore a class diagram in Visual Studio.
you select any class object in window and than right click on it then you select "Properties" menu Item and then a window will pups up that allow you to change selected class object.
or something like Auto Cad. when you draw a line you can right click on it and then select Properties menu item and then with appeared window you can change line's properties (like color of line or any thing like that).
now i want to create an application with an User Interface like these who mentioned on upper lines.
i want to create an UI that i cad draw circle and squares on it (with mouse clicks) and then when i want a "Properties" window will appeared to change objects's properties.
also with this capability that wheeling mouse wheel up-down will results in zoom in/out the screen (like Auto CAD).
finally my question is that is there any kind of frameworks or pre created controls that i can use them for achiving these goals or i have to implement all these my self?

thanks all and sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for your property grid:
[WPF Property Grid](http://wpg.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

for giving zoom capability i use [this](http://www.wpf-graphics.com/ZoomPanel.aspx) and for property windows i use [this](http://wpg.codeplex.com/).
thanks to Yogesh...